# How to join two dataframe of different database(mysql and postgres) and get an output as a csv file using python?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, postgresql, csv

As mentioned in the question I have the task of joining two data frames of different databases locally(MySQL and PostgreSQL) and need to get an output(dataset) in a CSV file. Let me tell you what I have done so far in the following:

1. Created a connection(con) using `mysql.connector.connect`
2. Meanwhile for postgres using `psycopg2` separately.
3. `df1 = pd.read_sql(sql='SELECT * FROM mydatabase.Empl_det', con=conn).to_csv(r'C:\Users\Aaru\Documents\Empl_det1.csv', index=False)` before doing this I have created a table in both MySQL and postgres....as a result I got a output in the form of csv.
4. Similarly to PostgreSQL `df2 = pd.read_sql(sql='SELECT * FROM postgres.public.salary_details', con=conn).to_csv(r'C:\Users\Aaru\Documents\Emp_sal.csv', index=False)` separately.
5. Now the thing is  I need to join these two data frames based on the common column and get an output in CSV file.

Sometimes I used to get `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax` for this MySQL version and I have gone through the documentation too....but I am not getting a  proper reference for my question.

I am using MySQL 8.0.21 version and PostgreSQL 10.
Can anyone help me in bringing out with the join? Hope that the above said will be helpful in getting out with answers.
Thanks a lot in advance!!

One more question:
Is it possible to do this and then merge?

```
   import pandas as pd 
   import mysql.connector
   import psycopg2

   conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",
                               user="user",
                               password="mypassword",
                               database="mydatabase"
                               )
mycursor_sql = conn.cursor()

con = psycopg2.connect(
    database="postgres", user="postgres", password="mypassword", host="localhost", port=5432)

cursor = con.cursor()

df1 = pd.read_sql(sql='SELECT * FROM mydatabase.Empl_det', con=conn).to_csv(
    r'C:\Users\Aaru\Documents\Empl_det1.csv', index=False)
df2 = pd.read_sql(sql='SELECT * FROM postgres.public.salary_details', con=conn).to_csv(
    r'C:\Users\Aaru\Documents\Emp_sal1.csv', index=False)

merged_df = df1.merge(df2, on='id')
merged_df.to_csv('join.csv')
print("Success")
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Is there any other way to do it?... Need a quick response as soon as possible.
Thanks

Comment: You need to merge them together?

Comment: @gtomer I need to join those based on a common column name eg:id

Comment: Why don't you try installing [mysql_fdw](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mysql_fdw) on your Postgresql server, access `mydatabase.Empl_det` as a foreign table and then join `Empl_det` and `salary_details` in a Postgresql query? This may be useful for many other cases too so that you would not have to perform join programmatically.

Comment: hi @Stefanov.sm, Since I am new to this, can u pls tell me with an example in detail...so that it would be easy for my understanding

Comment: @Aarudhra, I was not aware that you are new to this but am afraid that it will take more than an example. If you are interested in the topic you may start [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/ddl-foreign-data.html). I would be glad to assist if necessary.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
merged_df = df1.merge(df2, on='id')
merged_df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

For joining use [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-or-named-series-joining-merging) method, for writing use [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#writing-to-csv-format) method. But if you have a lot of data this can lead to a lack of memory on your machine.

Comment: Then what is the way to handle such cases with huge data?

Comment: Use distributed systems such as `spark` for example

Comment: That's not an easy question. You asked for storing the result to CSV and that's not the case when the data is big. So I think you need to try to do it with pandas first. Also how many data and ram do you have?

Comment: First, I am trying out with the above sample data actually